# Monitor only running at 60hz?

Tags: display, troubleshooting, refresh-rate

So I just bought a gaming monitor, the Samsung CRG5 144hz monitor. I have an intel core i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz   1.19 GHz, and an intel UHD graphics. The monitor came with its own HDMI cable, which I suppose should do 144hz 1080p. But when I connected both my laptop and the monitor, the monitor only goes to maximum 60hz in the Display Adapter Properties. I have windows 11.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is unlikely your laptop's HDMI port/GPU is capable of outputting a 144hz via HDMI. What is the exact model of your laptop? You need an HDMI 2.0 compliant port to use 1080p at high refresh rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable is not your issue - the laptop is. Even though I believe the HDMI port on the machine is technically HDMI 1.4b compliant (which should be able to push 1080p 144Hz and up to 4k 30Hz), Dell advertises the maximum resolution of the port at 1080p which indicates to me that the integrated graphics chip is not up to the task of pushing higher frame rates or resolutions.

You will need a machine with more graphics horsepower to make use of the 144Hz mode on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might not be the laptop. I have a Surface Pro 7, 10'th Gen Intel with integrated graphics. It runs 144Hz with no issues on the Samsung LC49J890DKRXEN, however, I just bought another Super Ultra Wide, the Samsung LS49A950UIUXEN and it's stuck at 60Hz.

I don't know what the issue is, I'm using the same connector, tried all the settings for both the monitor and the Surface.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1136522)